# Trying to account for no search results - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app for keeping a book journal and uses OpenLibrary API for book covers. I just realized it seems to break when someone adds a book that is not found in the API (still working with other books) -- the app looks up books by title and pulls the cover of the first search result. So when I get this error: `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass` I believe it is because there are no search results.

The following is the code triggering the error, specifically on my line 50 which is the one that begins `cover_id =`

```
 def create
    @book = current_user.books.new(params[:book])
    search_results = HTTParty.get("https://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=#{@book.title.gsub(' ', '+')}")
    search_results_json = JSON::parse(search_results)
    if search_results.blank? 
      redirect_to books_path, notice: 'Book not found.'
    else
    cover_id = search_results_json['docs'].first['cover_i']
    @book.cover_url = "http://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/#{cover_id}-L.jpg"
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save       
          user = current_user
          if user.add_to_likes(@book)
            #redirect_to current_user, :notice => "Added to your library!"
            #render :json => Book.find(params[:id])
            format.html { redirect_to success_path, notice: 'Book created! If approved we will add it to the Browse queue.' }
            format.json { render json: @book, status: :created, location: @book }
          end
        #format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        #format.json { render json: @book, status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      end
    end
  end
```

I've attempted to add a bit of code to check `if search_results.blank?` but that seems to have no affect.

Let me know if you think I'm on the right track with nil referring to no search results, and if there is a better way to account for this in the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either `search_results_json` is nil or `search_results_json['docs'].first` is returning nil.

Try using `puts search_results_json` to inspect what the contents are.

Also, your blank? check should be on `search_results_json` not `search_results` since that's the variable that gets used further.